# Need Help in optimizing the SQLalchemy query with recursive table

Tags: python, postgresql, optimization, sqlalchemy, recursive-query

I am pretty new in SQLalcemy and do not know yet all the functionality and possibilities in using it.
I am now trying to implement a CRUD method to my recursive table called 'Artifact':

```
class Artifact(Base):
    """
    Artifact table with defined columns and relationships.
    """

    __tablename__ = "artifact"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, autoincrement=True)
    parentId = db.Column(
        db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("artifact.id", name="artifact_parentId_fkey")
    )
    title = db.Column(db.String(100))
    notes = db.Column(db.String(500))
    startDate = db.Column(db.Date)
    endDate = db.Column(db.Date)
    extendedDate = db.Column(db.Date)
    artifactType = db.Column(db.Enum(ArtifactType))
    artifactStatus = db.Column(db.Enum(ArtifactStatus))
    artifactGroup = db.Column(db.Enum(ArtifactGroup))
    hourlyRate = db.Column(db.Numeric)
    price = db.Column(db.Numeric)
    taxes = db.Column(db.Numeric)
    effort = db.Column(db.Integer)
    settle = db.Column(db.Enum(SettleEnum))
    createInvoiceFor = db.Column(
        db.Date, default=lambda context: default_data(context, "startDate")
    )
    logo = db.Column(db.TEXT)
    contacts = db.Column(ARRAY(db.Integer))

    customerId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("customer.id"))
    accesses = relationship("ResourceAccess", backref="artifact")
```

And here is the CRUD I wrote:

```
    @classmethod
    def get_all_child_and_parent_records(
            cls, session, user_id: str, **filter_by
    ) -> List["Artifact"]:
        """
        Method to query all Artifact child and parent records from database.
        :param session: session maker
        :param user_id: accessing user ID.
        :param filter_by: Query filters
        :return: List[Artifact]
        """
        access_check = ResourceAccess.data_access(session, user_id)

        main_recursive = (
            session.query(Artifact)
            .filter_by(**{k: v for k, v in filter_by.items() if v is not None})
            .join(access_check, cls.id == access_check.c.artifactId)
            .cte("recursive", recursive=True)
        )

        child_query = (
            session.query(Artifact)
            .filter(Artifact.parentId == main_recursive.c.id)
            .join(access_check, cls.id == access_check.c.artifactId)
        )
        main_and_child_query = session.query(main_recursive.union_all(child_query))

        parent_query = (
            session.query(Artifact)
            .filter(Artifact.id == main_recursive.c.parentId)
            .join(access_check, cls.id == access_check.c.artifactId)
        )
        main_and_parent_query = session.query(main_recursive.union_all(parent_query))

        return main_and_child_query.all() + main_and_parent_query.all()[1:]
```

I know it is far from perfect but it works for now, and I pretty certain there is possibility how to optimize it, make faster, use less of code, etc.

Basically this CRUD needs to retrieve a list of records that are parent and children to the one that is sent to this CRUD (in filter_by always is sent the ID of the root object to which I need to find all parent and children, including nested).

The access join is an additional query that checks if user has access to the Artifact record, and return only artifact record if user has the access.

In return I am slicing the second query cause it duplicates the root artifact, that I do not need in my return list.

Here is additional short example how CRUD should work:

[Example image of Artifact data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZEEF.png)

If we want to GET Artifact 2, then in the 'parent' we will receive Artifact1 and in children we will receive Artifact4 and Artifact5. Artifact6 and Artifact3 will not be retrieved.

If we want to GET Artifact 4 then in the 'parent' we will receive Artifact2 and in it 'parent' we will receive "Artifact1", we will not receive any children, and Artifact5, Artifact6 and Artifact3 will not be retrieved.

I've been trying to use subqueries and unions but always I was missing some data in return, either the parent or children records were missing, either it returned only one level parent/children.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem & Solution

It looks you can traverse up and down with a recursive CTE (Common Table Expression). The basic idea is to fetch the main artifact, its children, its children's children, and so on, in a recursive manner until there are no more descendants. Similarly, we should fetch the parent of the main artifact, its parent's parent, and so on, in a recursive manner.

## Code

```
@classmethod
def get_all_child_and_parent_records(cls, session, user_id: str, **filter_by) -> List["Artifact"]:
    """
    Method to query all Artifact child and parent records from database.
    :param session: session maker
    :param user_id: accessing user ID.
    :param filter_by: Query filters
    :return: List[Artifact]
    """
    # Define the access check condition
    access_check = ResourceAccess.data_access(session, user_id)

    # Initialize the CTE
    recursive_cte = session.query(
        Artifact.id.label('current_id'),
        Artifact.parentId.label('parent_id')
    ).filter_by(**filter_by).cte(name="recursive_cte", recursive=True)

    # Define the recursive part of the CTE to get child and parent artifacts
    child_query = session.query(
        Artifact.id,
        Artifact.parentId
    ).filter(
        Artifact.parentId == recursive_cte.c.current_id
    ).join(access_check, Artifact.id == access_check.c.artifactId)

    parent_query = session.query(
        Artifact.parentId,
        Artifact.id
    ).filter(
        Artifact.id == recursive_cte.c.parent_id
    ).join(access_check, Artifact.id == access_check.c.artifactId)

    # Add the recursive part to the initial CTE
    recursive_cte = recursive_cte.union_all(child_query).union_all(parent_query)

    # Final query to get the Artifact details using the CTE
    final_query = session.query(Artifact).filter(
        Artifact.id.in_(session.query(recursive_cte.c.current_id))
    ).order_by(Artifact.id)

    return final_query.all()
```

This method first initialises the `recursive_cte` with the main Artifact you're interested in (filtered by `filter_by`). It then recursively adds both the child artifacts and parent artifacts to this CTE until there are no more descendants or ancestors. Finally, it queries the `Artifact` table to fetch the details for the artifacts listed in the CTE.

This will give you the main artifact, its parents, its parents' parents, and so on. Similarly, it will give you the main artifact, its children, its children's children, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I've tried your solution but it throws me an error:
 File "/home/vgurin/TiM-Project/customer-artifacts/api/model/db_models.py", line 766, in get_all_child_and_parent_records
    recursive_cte = recursive_cte.union_all(child_query).union_all(parent_query)
  File "/home/vgurin/.local/share/virtualenvs/customer-artifacts-JHQcZwgw/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 2153, in union_all
    assert is_select_statement(.......
WHERE artifact."parentId" = recursive_cte.current_id does not support union_all()